# jquery - how to reduce conditional statements that filter data from external file

Tags: jquery

How do I take the following code in my ajax request...

```
...
  success: function(data) {
      var $data = $(data);
      var data_topmenu             =  $data.filter("#menu")[0].outerHTML;
      var data_footer              =  $data.filter("#footer")[0].outerHTML;
      var data_submenu_about       =  $data.filter("#about")[0].outerHTML;
      var data_submenu_participate =  $data.filter("#participate")[0].outerHTML;
      var data_submenu_join        =  $data.filter("#join")[0].outerHTML;
      var data_submenu_support     =  $data.filter("#support")[0].outerHTML;

        //LOAD FILTERED DATA INTO DOM BASED ON TEXT VALUE OF ELEMENT
     $(".submenukey:contains('about')").html(data_submenu_about);
     $(".submenukey:contains('support')").html(data_submenu_support);
     $(".submenukey:contains('join')").html(data_submenu_join);
     $(".submenukey:contains('participate')").html(data_submenu_participate);

      }
        ...
```

and reduce the amount of conditional statements i need to make, just because I create a new var values....

Comment: `$('#submenukey').html(data_submenu_support);` will replace the innhtml of #submenukey with the result returned from the filter() function. Is this what you want?

Comment: exactly - and I wish I new how to do that...that is good enough for this example.  I also would like to know how can I make this a dynamic thing, this way it's not always a manual process. I have an example now posted on what I tried...

Comment: the data that is being returned is html code coming from an external HTML file.  That file has different ID's on it.  each ID is sitting on a div element.  Within each div element is an unordered list of links. Does that answer your question...?

Comment: Sort of, its a bit confusing, Can you put an example of the markup you expect to receive from the filter function and what's supposed to happen after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that is what you want ... you can try put selectors into an array and iterate through it:

```
success: function(data) {
      var $data = $(data);

      var array = ['menu', 'footer', 'about', 'participate', 'join', 'support'];

      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        $('.submenukey:contains("' + array[i] + '")').html($data.filter('#' + array[i])[0].outerHTML);

      }
  }
...
```

Comment: Thank you!  This shapes my perspective on brining more of a dynamic approach!